# Sound 'r' in English

Tags: british-english, phonetics, cinema

Below you see a clip from the movie "Clockwork Orange". Starting from 2:00 we hear how an officer speaks: he pronounced sound 'r' in an unusual way: vary close to russian sound 'р' ( e.g. 'rings' ).

https://youtu.be/Q1UUZSXFlyc?t=119

So, why he pronounced it like this? Does he have some accent? Or it is just an imitation of an animal's growl in order to make him look comically serious?

Comment: Isn't it called the *'trill R'*? (The way he pronounces 'rings').

Comment: The warder has exaggerated pronunciation of "chocolate" too.

Comment: I think he's just affecting a brisk and impersonal manner of speaking. The fierce prison warder Mr Mackay in the classic sitcom 'Porridge' (who has a Scottish accent) uses a similar manner. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUpE1-S0Gy4

Comment: The stereotype of army sergeant-majors involved them talking like that.

Comment: The character in the clip from Clockwork Orange is not speaking in a Scottish accent. He is using a form of diction which any British person alive at the time of the film's production would recognise, which I could describe as 'genteel working-class official'.